# Why do I get Error 'can't find variable $' and 'document not defined'

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I get the error

> 'Cant find variable $' in the console. In dreamweaver I get the error
>   '"document" is not defined. [no-undef].'

This is my script.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //dropdown menu
    $('.burger').click(function() {
        $('.menulist').slideToggle();
        $('.bar1').toggleClass('change1');
        $('.bar2').toggleClass('change2');
        $('.bar3').toggleClass('change3');
    });

    //contact information
    $('.contact-button').click(function() {
        $('.contact-details').toggle('fast');
    }); 
})
```

And these are the scripts at the bottom (before closing body) in HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This is the website: www.norameijburg.com

Comment: Make sure jQuery is not loaded twice.

Comment: Open your console : `The page at 'https://www.norameijburg.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

Comment: Check the `console`. You aren't using the `script` tag you mentioned in the question. Change it to `https`.

Comment: Yes, you quote "https" for the jquery.min.js but at your site you use "http" and get the above error telling you the request is blocked.

Comment: ... and ignore what dreamweaver tells you ;)

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Comment: Thanks! it works now!